# Shortcut to show Bluetooth drop-down list in Plasma panel

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, bluetooth, plasma-5

Instead of clicking with the cursor the panel applets (widget and tray icons) in order to show their drop-down window with list/options I prefer sometimes to use shortcuts: Meta-B for battery, Meta-V for volume and so on. Most of these applets have an option to set a shortcut:

[image]

There are other available shortcuts for notifications, clipboard, devices, and printers.

I remember that at some point I also had a shortcut that showed the Bluetooth drop-down window.

[image]

On my system now this option is absent. Right-clicking the tray icon, there is an option to "Configure Bluetooth" which opens the Bluetooth settings, but there is no option for the applet itself (and its shortcut).

Adding the Bluetooth widget (out of the systray) - the same thing.

Is there a way to force the drop-down window with a shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was ridiculously simple in fact. Keyboard shortcuts can be set also per "Entries" within "Configure System Tray": right click on it, and then "Entries".

[image]

Comment: Was looking for it in Keyboard Shortcuts. But it was in System Tray settings. As it is written in answer, i guess.